# Заполнение массива объектов с помощью геттеров и сеттеров

Tags: java, массивы, объекты, setter, getter

Программисты! Передо мной стоит задача заполнить `static` массив объектов полями, с помощью геттеров и сеттеров:

```
public String getRegnum() {
    return regnum;
}
    public void setRegnum(String regnum) {
        this.regnum = regnum;
    }
    public String getSpeciality() {
        return speciality;
    }
    public void setSpeciality(String speciality) {
        this.speciality = speciality;
    }

public int getExperience() {
    return experience;
}
public void setExperience(int experience) {
    this.experience = experience;
}

public String getEducation() {
    return education;
}

public void setEducation(String education) {
    this.education = education;
}

public String getDismissal() {
    return dismissal;
}

public void setDismissal(String dismissal) {
    this.dismissal = dismissal;
}

public String getCondition() {
    return condition;
}

public void setCondition(String condition) {
    this.condition = condition;
}

public int getMin() {
    return min;
}

public void setMin(int min) {
    this.min = min;
}
```

Чтобы ускорить процесс, занес все геттеры в `getAll`, а сеттеры - в `setAll`:

```
public String getAll () {
    return getRegnum() + getSpeciality() + getExperience() + getEducation() + getDismissal() + getCondition() + getMin();

}
public void setAll(String regnum, String speciality, int experience, String education, String dismissal, String condition, int min){
    this.regnum = regnum;
    this.speciality = speciality ;
    this.experience = experience ;
    this.education = education ;
    this.dismissal = dismissal;
    this.condition = condition;
    this.min = min;
}
```

Однако при попытке внести `getAll` и `setAll` в циклы, проходящие по моему `static` массиву, компилятор выдает ошибку 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

```
public class Main {

    static Applicant[] app = new Applicant[3];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i<app.length; i++){
//на этой строке выдает ошибку
           app[i].setAll("123A", "Java Junior Developer", 1, "KHPI", "02.08.18", "Freelance", 800);
        }
  for (int i = 0; i<app.length; i++){
            app[i].getAll();
        }
}
```

Как выйти из данного положения или я вообще не таким образом хочу внести объекты в свой массив?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Дело в том, что когда вы создаете массив на 3 элемента, вы не создаете 3 объекта внутри него. При создании массива, все его ячейки - становятся null. Вам надо явно создать объект для каждой ячейки, следующим образом :

```
for (int i = 0; i<app.length; i++){
           app[i] = new Applicant();
           app[i].setAll("123A", "Java Junior Developer", 1, "KHPI", "02.08.18", "Freelance", 800);
        }
```

Comment: Благодарю, заработало, но теперь при выводе данного массива, выводятся ссылки на объект (как я понимаю), а не его содержимое. С чем это может быть связано? Пример первого элемента: college.Applicant@4554617c

Comment: @MaxSquirrel попробуйте Arrays.toString(app) . Метод пробежится по всем вашим объектам, вызовет у них toString и соберет их вместе.

Comment: немного не понял, куда этот метод засунуть, пробовал перед циклом вывода, пробовал в него, однако результат остался таким же

Comment: @MaxSquirrel после цикла, который заполняет массив -  System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(app));

Comment: тогда он просто это всё через запятую перебирает: [college.Applicant@4554617c, college.Applicant@74a14482, college.Applicant@1540e19d]

Comment: @MaxSquirrel переопределите метод toString() http://www.internet-technologies.ru/articles/ispolzovanie-metoda-tostring-v-java.html

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает.

Comment: Если нужно сеттить много полей, используют шаблон `Builder`

Answer (score 2):

Метод `setAll` - это в данном случае конструктор со всеми полями. Ваш код может выглядеть так:

```java
SomeClass[] arr = new SomeClass[10];

arr[0] = new SomeClass("field10", "field20", "field30", "field40", 50, 60);
arr[1] = new SomeClass("field11", "field21", "field31", "field41", 51, 61);
arr[2] = new SomeClass("field12", "field22", "field32", "field42", 52, 62);
// ...
```